# Using of TVS diode in series and parallel

Tags: power, diodes, switching, tvs

[image]

This is an automotive system. The "LM2594M-5.0" input is from capacitor(Vout).an valve will be switch ON/OFF periodically(this valve has +24VDC/max1A). i think TVS1 is used for reserse polarity prorection and TVS2 and TVS3 are used for surgre current protection.

I know that TVS diode is used for over-voltage protection and spike dumping.

In switching system for normal condition what would be at the capacitor's positive terminal(Vout) if TVS1 is "P4SMA75A":Vcl=104,Vstandoff:71.3
and TVS2=TVS3="SM15T15A": standoff voltage=12.8,Vcl=21.2V/71A.

Comment: Welcome! Please draw a schematic.

Comment: Zero; there is no connection from Vout to +24V shown. What is a "switching system"? Why have 12V diodes been chosen for a "+24V" system? What ratings are required, is this an automotive environment or etc.?

Comment: yes,this is an automotive system.TVS2 and TVS3 are intended for spike clamping.

Comment: The output(Vout) will go to voltage regulator (+24V or +12V )to +5V .The +24V will control also On/OFF switch somewhere else which casuse spike on this power portion.

Comment: Sorry friend,the schematic was wrong,my mistake!!!,I updated it now.

Comment: Please follow best practices for drawing schematics. Positive voltages point up, ground and negative point down. Signal and current flow is from left to right. TVS2 and TVS3 should be pointing up as they are in parallel with C1.

Comment: There are four figures in your post, including I think two versions of the original; could you indicate which one is the update? | Could you explain what "switching system" means? | What are the input/supply ratings? Regulator type or ratings? | Do you have a specification, standards, etc. we could see, or that you could reference, that would help explain your application?

Comment: Ok,i clean the schematic a bit,the rating for supply is 24VDC/1A.The "LM2594M-5.0" input is from capacitor(Vout).an valve will be switch ON/OFF periodically(this valve has +24VDC/max1A). i think TVS1 is used for reserse polarity prorection and TVS2 and TVS3 are used for surgre current protection.